# Using regex to remove unwanted end of a string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm struggling a little with some regex execution to remove trailing extraneous characters.  I've tried a few ideas that I found here, but none are quite what I'm looking for.

Data looks like this (only one column of data):

```
City1[edit]

City2 (University Name)

City with a Space (University Name)

Etc.
```

Basically, the trouble that I run into here is I can't necessarily remove everything after a space because sometimes a city name includes a space ("New York City").

However, what I think I could do is a three step approach:

1. Replace anything between [],(),{} sets of characters (this will remove the "edit" and the "University Name" in the sample data.
2. Replace the [],(),{} type characters since those are now extra characters.
3. Trim any trailing spaces (which will leave the spaces in city names such as St. Paul)

I have two main questions:
 1. Is there a way to do this in one command, or will it have to be three separate commands?
 2. How do you remove characters in between specific characters using regex?

Code that I have attempted:

1. `DF[0].replace(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z*]$', "", regex=True, inplace = True)`---however this only replaced the final iteration of the special characters
2. `DF[0].replace(r'[\W+$|^0-9a-zA-Z*]',"",regex=True, inplace=True)`--unfortunately this just replaced everything, leaving all my data blank

Comment: Do you *know* that `(` or `[`, or `{` marks data you want to remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always know the bracket characters that will come first you can do:

Create data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'names':['City1[edit]', 
                          'City2 (University Name)', 
                           'City with a Space {University Name}']})
```

Then replace everything after first bracket.

```
df.names.str.replace('\[.*|\(.*|\{.*', '').str.strip()
```

Output

```
0                City1
1                City2
2    City with a Space
```

Comment: There are literal characters and special characters in regex. All the brackets are special characters and need to be escaped with the backslash to treat them as literal characters. The bar `|` is regex for 'or' and `.*` matches everything. See here for more: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Comment: How do you interpret this regex?  Is it basically: "After the [ character, replace everything; then, after the { character, replace everything; then, remove any trailing spaces"

Comment: @StephenJuza - I'm not too familiar with pandas but it looks like it finds the literal `[` or `(` or `{` and replaces it and everything afterwards with an empty string `''`. It uses the 'or' operator `|` so it's not a sequential attack of `x then y then z`.

Answer (score 0):

A regexp would be a relatively easy way to do this.

```
import re

p = re.compile('(\(|\[|\{)[A-Za-z\ ].+(\)|\]|\})')
dirty = 'City with a Space (University Name)'
cleaned = p.sub('', dirty).strip()
print(cleaned)
```

Answer (score 0):

option with `split`
look for zero or one space followed by a `[`, `(`, or `{`
split at that point and take first part

```
df.names.str.split(r'\s*[\[\{\(]').str[0]

0                City1
1                City2
2    City with a Space
Name: names, dtype: object
```